# Why is it forbidden to wear glasses when leaving the plane during an emergency?

Tags: safety, emergency

On my last flight with Iberia I noticed in the safety guidelines that you are not allowed to wear glasses during an emergency.
[image: Image of safety guidelines]

If I have to take off my glasses I would have serious problems seeing what is going on. So this makes no sense to me.

Why would I have to remove my glasses?

Comment: I think it might be referring to sunglasses, but I agree with you that it is a confusing depiction

Comment: I once asked service staff since I also need glasses to actually see something. They told me it refers to reading glasses, sunglasses and any others you don't actually wear all the time - simply because people would (a) waste time searching, thus delaying their own evacuation and obstructing others' and (b) sun/reading glasses not worn but attached to clothes could break and injure the wearer, bystanders or damage equipment.

That's at least what I was told.

Comment: Rightmost picture... Pull at a woman's skirt? What is that arrow supposed to point at?

Comment: @mins If she stays low, she can avoid the automatic machine gun fire in the aisle.

Comment: @mins Avoiding smoke in a burning plane.  See the yellow puffs of smoke above her.

Comment: @Sanchises the location of the door release latch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because they don't want people holding up the evacuation by searching for their glasses.   It does not mean you are not allowed to bring glasses if you are wearing them but passengers blocking the aisle to search for their glasses would slow the evacuation and risk lives.   They do want you to actually take off your high heels and leave your luggage because these can actually slow you down.   This should be portrayed more clearly.